# Class examples does not add up to cardinality in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, amazon-sagemaker

I am using AWS Sagemaker to train a Tensorflow image classification model. During training, I get the following log messages:

> Cardinality of train dataset: 1492
> Number of class examples in train dataset: {'Approved': 36, 'Rejected': 36}
> Cardinality of validation dataset: 328
> Number of class examples in validation dataset: {'Approved': 9, 'Rejected': 9}

My understanding is that the number of class examples should sum to give the cardinality. In my case I have 36 'Rejected' and 1456 'Approved' in my training dataset. However the logs seem to imply that only 36 examples of each class exist. Similarly, in the validation set there are 9 'Rejected' and 319 'Approved' but only 9 examples of each can be found.

I want to understand why the sum of examples doesn't equal the cardinality. I suspect that Tensorflow is assuming I have a balanced dataset and I need to somehow specify that the classes are unbalanced. Is this the case and if so how can I apply class weightings to my estimator.

For reference, my estimator is defined as follows:

```
ic_estimator = Estimator(
role=role_arn,
image_uri=train_image_uri,
source_dir=train_source_uri,
model_uri=train_model_uri,
entry_point="transfer_learning.py",
instance_count=1,
input_mode='FastFile',
instance_type=train_instance_type,
max_run=3600,
hyperparameters=hyperparameters,
binary_mode=True,
objective_metric_name='validation:recall',  # Sets the metric to determine the best model by
metric_definitions=[{'Name': 'validation:recall', 'Regex': "val_recall: (\d+\.\d+)"}],
output_path=s3_output_path,
base_job_name=training_job_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are seeing same numbers between Approved and Rejected, I recommend to check your training script, and make sure you are passing correct data to Tensorflow.

Also, please try to find who is printing the "Cardinality of train dataset:" log. I briefly checked the source code of Tensorflow, but didn't find that log line. There may be an issue in this log printing code itself.